# In a deck.gl GeojsonLayer, how can I hide individual polygons?

Tags: geojson, deck.gl

I have a polygon [GeoJSON layer](https://deck.gl/docs/api-reference/layers/geojson-layer) in my deck.gl map. To avoid having to reload many polygons in many user interactions, I would like to pre-load all polygons and then change their visibility. I tried to achieve this by setting the fill color (and also line color and line width, but there it's hidden in the functions) to null depending on the polygon properties.

```
        new deck.GeoJsonLayer({
            id: 'polygon-layer',
            data: family,
            pickable: true,
            getPosition: d => d.geometry.coordinates,
            filled: true,
            getFillColor: d => show(d) ? hexToIntColor(d.properties.color) : null,
            lineWidthUnits: "pixels",
            getLineWidth: highlighted,
            getLineColor: highlighedColor,
            lineWidthMinPixels: 1,
            visible: true,
            onClick: displayProperties,
            updateTriggers: {
                getLineWidth: [highlightedMap, highlightedCode],
                getLineColor: [highlightedMap, highlightedCode],
                getFillColor: [highlightedMap, highlightedCode]
            }
        })
```

The result is very much not what I expected

[image: Screen Shot of Map View]

How *do* I set individual polgons to not be displayed? (And where do these strange black gradients come from which I see instead of just seeing the pink and coastline from the background map?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [DataFilterExtension](https://deck.gl/examples/data-filter-extension/), setting `filterRange` to `[1, 1]` means that only entities that meet the condition (1) will be rendered, and not (0):

```
new deck.GeoJsonLayer({
  ...
  getFilterValue: (d) => Number(show(d)),
  filterRange: [1, 1],
  extensions: [new DataFilterExtension({ filterSize: 1 })],
  updateTriggers: {
    getFilterValue: [yourTrigger]
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that advice looks solid, but following it in practice led to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71259148/

Comment: I messed something up then. It works fine now, thanks for pointing me to it!