# What causes ‘Model needs a program’ with a DataFilterExtension?

Tags: deck.gl

Following the advice in [an answer to my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71234233/1274613), I added a `deck.DataFilterExtension` to my deck.gl GeoJSON-layer to be able to filter some polygons. The following is the core of my setup; I hope I'm not leaving out any important details by shortening it.

```
<script>
let highlightedMap = null;

render();

function render() {
    layers = [new deck.GeoJsonLayer({
            id: 'polygon-layer',
            data: family,
            pickable: true,
            getPosition: d => d.geometry.coordinates,
            filled: true,
            getFillColor: d => (visibility(d) ? hexToIntColor(d.properties.color) : [0, 0, 0, 0]),
            lineWidthUnits: "pixels",
            getLineWidth: highlighted,
            getLineColor: highlightedColor,
            lineWidthMinPixels: 1,
            visible: true,
            onClick: displayProperties,
            updateTriggers: {
                getLineWidth: [highlightedMap],
                getLineColor: [highlightedMap],
                getFillColor: [highlightedMap],
                getFilterValue: [highlightedMap]
            },
            getFilterValue: visibility,
            filterRange: [1, 2],
            filterEnabled: false,
            extensions: [new deck.DataFilterExtension({filterSize: 1})]
        })];
    deckgl.setProps({layers});
}

</script>

    <!-- Libraries in the end for faster page loading-->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/deck.gl/dist/dist.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@deck.gl/carto/dist/dist.dev.js"></script>
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/@turf/turf@6/turf.min.js'></script>
    <link href="https://libs.cartocdn.com/mapbox-gl/v1.13.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://libs.cartocdn.com/mapbox-gl/v1.13.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
```

Initially, `visibility` returns 0 and nothing is rendered despite the `filterEnabled: false`, but after a user interaction, it returns 1 or 2 for some polygons so things should definitely appear, but instead, I see on the console

```
Error: update of PathLayer({id: 'polygon-layer-polygons-stroke'}): Model needs a program
    assert https://unpkg.com/deck.gl/dist/dist.dev.js:45267
    _checkProgram https://unpkg.com/deck.gl/dist/dist.dev.js:27146
    initialize https://unpkg.com/deck.gl/dist/dist.dev.js:26814
    Model https://unpkg.com/deck.gl/dist/dist.dev.js:26774
    _getModel https://unpkg.com/deck.gl/dist/dist.dev.js:105017
    [...]
```

both for the polygon fill and for the polygon strokes. I cannot make head or tails of this, especially because to my JavaScript-untrained eyes, `program` actually appears to be a WebGLProgram.

[image: Screenshot of Firefox debug console at the error location]

Things are fine, everything shows up nicely, without the filter-specific lines

```
            getFilterValue: [highlightedMap]
        },
        getFilterValue: visibility,
        filterRange: [1, 2],
        filterEnabled: false,
        extensions: [new deck.DataFilterExtension({filterSize: 1})]
```

What could be going wrong here?

Comment: Hey! Please create a codepen (with fake data if you want), reproducing the issue, so should be easier to help you

Comment: I'll try! I'm diving head-first into all of this and don't always know how to best do things yet.